# React : state property initialized in constructor to some value but returns undefined when rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state-management

In the following component, I have a state property which is initialized in constructor to a value of 5. But when i am using it inside render then it returns undefined. I don't understand why.

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    loadcomplete: false,
    twitterfeed: {
      techcrunch: [],
      laughingsquid: [],
      appdirect: []
    },
    tweetCount: 30
  };
}

render() {
  let { tweetCount } = this.state.tweetCount;
  console.log(tweetCount, "tweetcount");
  return(<div></div>)
}
```

Comment: you are not passing props

Comment: also, `let { tweetCount } = this.state.tweetCount;` should be `let { tweetCount } = this.state;` or `let tweetCount = this.state.tweetCount;`

Comment: @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala it doesnt make difference with props

Comment: Yes. Sorry my bad . Thanks :)

Comment: also don't forget to call `constructor(props) {super(props) ...}` to properly initialise the constructor with extended functionality from `Component` class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be unpacking `this.state` instead of `this.state.tweetCount`

`let { tweetCount } = this.state.tweetCount` is ~ equivalent to `let tweetCount = this.state.tweetCount.tweetCount`

use

`let { tweetCount } = this.state;`

**edit**: and yes, as other people have pointed out, you should be correctly passing props into the constructor and passing it to the parent class via `super` - but that's not why `tweetCount` is `undefined`

Comment: you only need to pass `props` to `super` if your constructor needs access to `this.props`.  But anyway, much easier to just use member initialization syntax and let the compiler write the constructor correctly for you.